# Show that there are two, $a_i$ and $a_j$ with $i≠j,$ such that either $a_i+a_j$ or $a_i- a_j$ is divisible by $100.$

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose $(a_1,a_2,…,a_{52}$) are integers, not necessarily distinct. Show that there are two, $a_i$ and $a_j$ with $i≠j$, such that either $a_i+a_j$ or $a_i−a_j$ is divisible by $100$. Show that this is not necessarily true for integers $(a_1,a_2,…,a_{51}).$

If we divide $a_i$ by $100$, we get 99 possible remainders- hence we can get 52 distinct remainders on dividing each of 52 distinct $a_i$'s by 100. Can't proceed from here.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Assume at least two of them are non distinct, then their subtraction would be 0 and 0 is divisible by anything. Therefore, assume all of them are distinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each index $i$, set $b_{i} = a_{i} \pmod{100}$ so that we obtain a new list of $52$ numbers $(b_{1}, b_{2}, \ldots b_{52})$ where $0 \leq b_{i} \leq 99$.

If there exist indices $i$ and $j$ for which $b_{i} = b_{j}$, we're done since $b_{i} - b_{j} \equiv 0 \pmod{100}$ (i.e. their difference is divisible by $100$). So we can consider the case in which all of the $b_{i}'s$ are different.

If all of the $b_{i}'s$ take on different values, there must exist two indices $i$ and $j$ such that $b_{i} + b_{j} \equiv 0 \pmod{100}$. This is true by the Pigeonhole Principle because we can consider the $100$ possible values that the $b_{i}$'s can take on in pairs as follows: $\{\{1, 99\}, \{2, 98\}, \{3, 97\}, \cdots \{49, 51\}\}.$ We're guaranteed that at least two integers will lie in the same pair (and by construction, the sum of these two integers will be divisible by $100$).

Comment: You only really need the final paragraph. If two of the $b_i$ are equal, they will still be in the same pigeonhole. Whether you have to add or subtract to get to $0\bmod100$ will of course change, but still.